# c++ find_if can't find the predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm getting the error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘findByPosition::findByPosition(std::vector<int>::size_type&, std::vector<int>::size_type&)’
```

And when I cast `i` & `k` to `int` i get:

```
no matching function for call to ‘findByPosition::findByPosition(int, int)’
```

I don't know what's the problem with my predicate. I've overloaded the `()` operator as needed:

```
struct findByPosition
{
    const Node needle;
    findByPosition(const Node& sought) : needle(sought) {}
    bool operator()(int i,int j) const
    {
        return ((needle.i == i) && (needle.j == j));

    }
};

SparseMatrix& SparseMatrix::operator*=(const SparseMatrix &other)
{
    SparseMatrix SparseMatrixResult(_numRow, other._numCol);
    vector<Node>::iterator rowMulti, colMulti;

    if(_numCol != other._numRow)
    {
        // error multiplying
    }

    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != (unsigned int)_numRow; i++) {

            for(std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j != (unsigned int)_numCol; j++) {

                for(std::vector<int>::size_type k = 0; k != (unsigned int)_numCol; k++)
                {
                    rowMulti = find_if(_matrix.begin(), _matrix.end(), findByPosition(i,k));
                }
            }
        }

    *this = SparseMatrixResult;
    return *this;
}
```

`_matrix` is of type:

```
vector<Node> _matrix;
```

Comment: how do you use rowMulti if you find the element? I only see a few loops but doesn't do anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `findByPosition(i,k)` you are actually **trying to call the constructor**, not the `operator()`

You need to **define a constructor** that you can then use at that line to **generate an object**. `find_if` then will call `theobject(i,j)` **internally** to invoke the `operator()`

You can see this from the error

> no matching function for call to ‘findByPosition::findByPosition(int, int)’

It is trying to find the **constructor**.

To correctly use the predicate, you need to actually flip your operator and your constructor. The constructor should take `i,j` as it is common to all calls of the functor, and the operator should take reference to the `const Node&` since that is the element type of the matrix and is the datatype that the functor will be called with.

```
struct findByPosition
{
    findByPosition(int _i, int _j) : i(_i), j(_j) {}
    bool operator()(const Node& needle) const
    {
        return ((needle.i == i) && (needle.j == j));

    }
private:
    int i,j;
};
```

With this, the constructor will construct an object with `i`,`j` saved, which will then be passed to your `find_if` function.

Answer (score 3):

`Lambda` is a better option for simple search if you use `C++11`

```
rowMulti = find_if(_matrix.begin(), _matrix.end(),
                  [=](const Node& n){return n.i==i && n.j == k; });
```